# strapi(4) not able to display image on frontend UI

Tags: reactjs, strapi

I am able to fetch data from strapi but i am not able to display it on frontend UI

image url is showing in console but i am not able to display it on UI.

[[[console log data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBopK.png)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n85n5.png)

[is there any fault in this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPpmh.png)

If anyone can help me with this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.